# Problem when using cx_Freeze: "cannot import name 'tf2'"

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, cx-freeze

I have a code in python and I used cx_Freeze to convert it to an .exe. This task works without any error.
But when I try to run my .exe the following error happens:

> from tensorflow.python import tf2
>   ImportError: cannot import name 'tf2'

My `ann.py` code is:

```
import numpy as np
import sys
```

.
.
.

```
X_test=XinN
Y_test=XoutN


#Criando o modelo
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

modelo = Sequential()

for i in range(int((num_par-4)/2)):
   modelo.add(Dense(int(parametros[i+4]), kernel_initializer='normal',activation=ativacao(int(parametros[i+5])))) #camadas ocultas
modelo.add(Dense(num_out, kernel_initializer='normal',activation=ativacao(int(parametros[num_par-1])))) #camada de saída

modelo.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_squared_error')

hist = modelo.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=800, verbose=0, batch_size=10,validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))

XobsoutN=modelo.predict(XobsN)
Xobsout=XobsoutN*(max_out-min_out)+min_out
np.savetxt("Xobsout.txt",Xobsout.transpose(),delimiter='\t')

loss=[" "," "]
loss[0] = hist.history['loss']
loss[1] = hist.history['val_loss']

np.savetxt("erro.txt",loss,delimiter='\t')
```

And my `setyp.py` for cx_Freeze is:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys

base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = None


executables = [Executable("ANN.py", base=base)]

packages = ["idna"]

options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'includes':['atexit', 'numpy.core._methods', 'numpy.lib.format'],
        'packages':packages,
    },

}

import os

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\tcl\\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\tcl\\tk8.6"

setup(
    name = "Nome Executavel",
    options = options,
    version = "1.0",
    description = 'Descricao do seu arquivo',
    executables = executables
)
```

Anyone can help me to solve this error?

I had many others errors using cx_Freeze and this forum was pretty helpful to solve all of them. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `"tensorflow"` to the `packages` list in your `setup.py` script:

```
 packages = ["idna", "tensorflow"]
```